# what does a single couple of brackets mean in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm reading [High Performance JavaScript](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596802806.do). In this book the author gave the following code:

```
function execute(code) {
  eval(code);

  function subroutine(){
    return window;
  }

  var w = subroutine();

  //what value is w?
};
```

and he ran the function with the following statement:

```
execute("var window = {};")
```

And he said:

> In this case, eval() creates a local window variable in execute(), so w
>   ends up equal to the local window instead of the global. There is no
>   way to know if this is the case until the code is executed, which
>   means the value of the window identifier cannot be predetermined.

I don't know what does the bare brackets `(code);` mean here. I tried his code and I got w as the global Window instance. Not the "created local window"(the empty object). I want to know what happened...

Comment: There is no bare `(code);` there. Perhaps you're reading some bogus pirate version of the book?

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because OP is using a copy of the book that was sent through an XSS filter and had all the occurrences of `eval` stripped out.

Answer (score 2):

What's happening is that the `eval()` in the code sample executes the code in that string. That code creates a local variable called `window`, and assigns an empty object to it.

The point is that with that particular string, the `window` in subroutine() is referring to that variable, but if it had been a completely different string with no mention of `window`, the `window` in subroutine could have ended up referring to the global `window` object.

The point is that this is completely bonkers in terms of having predictable code, both for the person writing the code, and for the JS engine trying to optimize it, and for that reason you should avoid doing this.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. But that's not what I want to know. What I want to know is what does a bare couple of brackets with a string(describes a js statement) in means. Just like the statement `(code);` in the author's codes.

Comment: @cosmozhang `(code);` does nothing whatsoever. There's something wrong with your copy of the book because the actual book doesn't have that.

Comment: Well, that's really sad :( ...... Thank you ~

Comment: @cosmozhang What's really sad is using an author's work without paying for it. Please buy the book (or at least borrow it from someone who has bought it).

Comment: Yes, you're right. I'll get a genuine book later, from our library.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` is an object literal, creating a blank object.

However, his code is totally wrong. You can't just execute arbitrary code like that - you'd need to use `eval()`. So, there is no local `window` object. He just ignored a string, and returned the real window.

Comment: The code in the book uses `eval`. There's a transcription error in the question.

Comment: I also suspect like you all. But the author said before this code snippet that: "Both the with statement and the catch clause of a try-catch statement, as well as a function containing (), are
all considered to be dynamic scopes.". So what does he mean by "()" in this sentence then?

Comment: @cosmozhang As I've been saying, there's something wrong with your book. The actual book says "Both the `with` statement and the `catch` clause of a `try-catch` statement, as well as a
function containing `eval()`, are all considered to be _dynamic scopes_." It seems that somehow, all the occurrences of "eval" got stripped out. Are you reading a legit copy of the book?